# Is it necessary to mysql real escape when using alter table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I noticed the other day that I cannot bind variables when using PDO with ALTER TABLE for example the following example will not work,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("ALTER TABLE emblems ADD ? TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD ? DATETIME NOT NULL"); 
$q -> execute(array($emblemDB, $emblemDB . 'Date'));
```

So is it necessary to use mysql_real_escape string and do it like below,

```
// ESCAPE NAME FOR MYSQL INSERTION
$emblemDB = mysql_real_escape_string($emblemDB);
// INSERT EMBLEM DETAILS INTO DATABASE
$q = $dbc -> prepare("ALTER TABLE emblems ADD " . $emblemDB . " TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD " . $emblemDB . "Date DATETIME NOT NULL");
$q -> execute();
```

Or do I not need to add in `mysql_real_escape_string`? As the only thing the query can do is ADD columns?

Thanks

Comment: Does `$emblemDB` come directly from user input?

Comment: Yes, it has annoyed me really because I cannot bind parameters and I need to do alot of these types of queries!

Comment: Is it the best idea to add columns based on user input? I can think of many other ways to achieve what I *think* you are trying to do.

Comment: I figured not but in my case it might be the best solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends. If you directly use user input in your query, you should use it. If you don't, the user could delimit the query and throw a `DROP` statement after it.

When a user would input:

```
somekindofname TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'; DROP TABLE emblems --
```

Your query would become:

```
ALTER TABLE emblems ADD somekindofname TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'; DROP TABLE emblems -- TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' somekindofname; DROP TABLE emblems -- Date DATETIME NOT NULL
```

Your database will execute the `ALTER TABLE`, execute the `DROP TABLE` and ignore the comment at the end.

Comment: Ok thanks this is what I was after, I cannot believe PDO doesn't support it!